# difference between sharepoint and public folder - trustworthy source

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sharepoint, attachments, public-folders

when I add a link in outlook mail to an htm file located in sharepoint...clicking the link opens the page with no problems.

when the same file is located in a network folder a popup appear "you should only open attachment from a trustworthy source." is there anything I can do to avoid this message? make the folder trusted or something. there are alot of users...unchecking the checkbox is not a good solution for me.

Comment: What `href` are you using to add the link to the share?

Comment: sorry for not sharing the exact path but the good is:https://a/b/c.htm  ... the problemaric one is \\a\b\c.htm... when writing the unswer I understood how it "knows" its a file and not a web page. the question is if i can turn it into a web page without a webserver

Comment: Well the question was more or less if you actually just used `\\share\file.htm` or actually `file://\\share\file.htm` which might make a different. It's also unclear whenever you tried to use the actual FQDN (so `\\share.domain.com\file.html`) or whenever you only have that problem from within your company network. There is no way to make that folder trusted as far as I know. That page will also run into several issues with local file restrictions. So the other question would be why you don't just put it on an actual webserver if you have access to it?

Comment: you are right I put in the link \\a\b\c. htm in publisher app and it change in to file:///\\a...  I need to get a webfolder. thank for your first qusetion, it made me understand the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the specifics on how Outlook determines this. But you might want to check which value you're actually using for you link. Depending on who is receiving the mail it could make a huge difference what is actually used as the link target.

In your answers to my questions you said that you're using `\\share\file.htm`. This usually would be transformed to `file://\\share\file.htm` in order to make it a file link that references a local resource. Depending on who is accessing the file it could already help to include the FQDN of the link (`\\share.domain.tld\file.htm`) in order to make it obvious that it's part of the "trusted" network. There i no way to make a location individually trusted that I know of.

Even if the user is able to access the link directly, depending on what that page contains you will run into various restrictions in regards to local resources and script execution and so on. You might be able to somewhat influence this behavior for Internet Explorer by putting `\\share.domain.tld` into one of the "lower" security zones.

In order to have less trouble with all of this, I'd just put it on a web server. Especially since it sounds like you'd have "easy" access to one in order to host the file.